# Session communication between servers

Tags: networking, communication

Imagine a huge chatting network, something on the scale of Microsoft's MSN. Such a network has thousands of servers with multiple server types. Think of this:

A user is always connected to one server, this server is called a dispatch server and this server will be used to communicate status changes, incoming and outgoing conversation requests, etc. The user is connected to this server as long as he is connected to the network.

When a user starts a new conversation, or an other user talkes to the user, the dispatch server will create a session on a whiteboard server and send the address of this server together with metadata to both users. The whiteboard server manages this chat session.

Now think of this: User A is connected to dispatch server A and user B to dispatch server B. User A changes his online status (from online to away) and his clients informs dispatch server A.

What will happen next? How will dispatch server B know about this change in a network with thousands of dispatch servers. How do dispatch servers communicate among each other?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subscription of users that the current user is connected to. The servers uses this list to know what others to update - so there are less servers involved

Comment: Something like this?: Dispatch servers communicate which users it has connected to an other server which holds a dictionary of users and dispatch servers?